# format specifier to exclude '=' in C

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

Quick question: I am using data from a .conf file to connect to a Gameserver; I'm using sscanf to parse through the file, whitespaces being ignored as they should, however to test my programs efficiency, I took out all whitespaces on the Port-number line, an voilà, it's not working anymore.... 
The original format in the .conf file ist just plain Portnumber=XXXX; How can I make sscanf() exclude de equal sign? I'm using it as follows:

```
sscanf(line, "%s = %s", parameter_name, parameter_value);   
    debug(parameter_name);
    debug(parameter_value);
```

and parameter_name just saves the entire line at once... I tried using

```
    sscanf(line, "%s %[^=]s", parameter_name, parameter_value);
```

to make him save the second parameter while using everything else aside the '=', but it is not working... any one have an idea?  I can't seem to find a real full list of format specifier tags on the net...

cheers

Answer (score 0):

`man scanf` should give you the full list of identifiers and their description.

Anyway, none of your attempts works because the first `%s` will eat everything until it finds a whitespace. This is the default behavior. You need to use `%[^=]` in the first format specifier:

```
sscanf(line, "%[^= ] = %s", parameter_name, parameter_value);
```

Comment: Thanks! However now the second char array(s) isn't being stored in the parameter_value variable....

Comment: @SpadeJohnsson do you have space between =?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sscanf(line,"%[^=]=%s",...)`?

Comment: Yes and no - tested it with both whitespaces in and out, both not working properly...

Comment: @VaughnCato is correct. His credit for the answer. I updated it.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato More likely `" %[^=]=%s"`  (add space before %[] as that does not drop leading whitespace like %s.)

Comment: Or maybe `" %[^=]= %s"`?

Comment: @VaughnCato, whitespace in `*scanf` consumes _any_ whitespace, not _at least one_ whitespace. In other words, it consumes `\s*` not `\s\+` (C11, 7.21.6.2.5). So there's no point in removing the whitespace. In fact, it's better to leave whitespace around `=` in case whitespace appears again one day. What @chux said is very true, though.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space in the specifier for the parameter name: `" %[^= ] = %s"`? That would match both the version with and without white space around the equals sign. Otherwise, the parameter name might end up having trailing spaces.

Comment: @MarianV `" %[^=]=%s"` and `" %[^=]= %s"` scan the same.  The space in front of `"%s"` does toss whitespace, but `"%s"` tosses leading whitespace anyways.

Comment: @MOehm Agree that `" %[^= ] = %s"` is even better than my suggestion.  It could be `" %[^= ] =%s"`, which does the same thing.